# ruby on rails what's the best way to add a column to a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration

My question is about finding a convenient way to add, remove, rename and change type of columns in a SQLite data structure.

I have a Ruby on Rails form that has multiple input text fields like the following (simplified):

```
<%= form_for(@Product, :html => {:name => "product_name", :id => "product_id"}) do |form| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.flag "Input 1" %>
        <%= form.text_field :Input_1 %>
        <%= form.flag "Input 2" %>
        <%= form.text_field :Input_2 %>
        ..., etc.
    </div>
<% end %>
```

So far, I followed the procedure described in RoR Migration Guide, so every time I needed to add a new text field, say Input n, I generated a migration for it, like this

```
rails generate migration AddInputToProducts Input_n:string
```

then I ran the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

The problem with this procedure is that once the migration is generated and ran, I no more have a trace of the exact name I used for the migration (Input_n in this example) unless I immediately create an entry for it in my RoR form and keep it there for ever. The results is that my table now has multiple entries I created thinking I would use them but I actually don't need them anymore, I don't remember their exact name and I'd like to either remove, re-use, rename or change their type.

My question is twofold:

1. Is there is a better and more convenient way to add columns to an existing table that would be more practical than running migrations as described in the guide?
2. How can I list, remove, rename or change type of existing columns in my data structure?

Comment: How about giving these columns a proper, meaningful name? Also, you know that migrations can be reverted, right? They have a `down` method.

Comment: @NiklasB. Except if they're already been committed you should create a new (reverse) migration.

Comment: No matter how much effort I put into using meaningful names, I always make mistakes with "_", "-", plurals, ..., etc. and end up messing up my names. Also to write a reverse migration, I have to remember the exact names I used !

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the db folder there is a file named schema.rb which have all the information about your tables including the names of the columns. There is the list.

For removing, renaming etc, migrations are perfect, but there is nothing stopping you from using other tools like Mysql Query browser (granted you are using MySQL).

Comment: Thanks Henrik for the prompt response. I looked at those files for 2 of my tables and they both have errors like "# Could not dump table "playlists" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'select_field' for column 'SongList'"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do the migrations using the tool, then you can use a GUI for the Database you use (SQLite) and you can just make the changes there.

Comment: Thanks stormlifter for the suggestion. Can you recommend a GUI sw that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you generate a migration, an associated file is created in `db/migrate` that you can inspect and adjust as required. As a matter of convention it's usually bad form to alter a migration that has already been applied. If you need to make changes, either unapply the migration if it's only been applied to your machine with `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=nnn` where `nnn` is the version serial, or create a second migration that undoes the first.

The more complicated your development and deployment environment is, the more careful you will have to be with managing your migrations.

If you don't care about your data, you can always `rake db:migrate:reset` to build from the ground up. I do this often during the early stages of development when fine-tuning the database structure. Once I get it working I'll then commit it and make additional migrations to alter it from that point forward. Remember that `reset` will effectively drop and recreate your database, so don't ever run this on a production system.

Comment: Thanks tadman for the help. Does that mean that you keep record of all migrations you create? In my project, I keep adding and new columns and migration names are not always explicit about what they contain, so I sometimes delete migration files after I commit them, hence my question

Comment: You should never delete migrations if they've been applied. The point of migrations is to have a complete record of how you've arrived at the current schema. In other words, starting with nothing but the source base including the migrations you should be able to migrate from an empty database to the current schema step-by-step using the migrations.

Comment: Migrations become especially important when you're working with multiple instances of the same database. A migration acts as a patch to modify the schema in some specific way, so you can easily bring other databases up to date using them. Most applications will have, at the very least, one or more development databases and one production database. Often you'll have an intermediate step or two for preview and testing purposes. All of these need to be versioned using migrations.

Comment: Thanks tadman for the advice. I'll stick to this best practice in the future.